# How to get my lokinet address after intsalling lokinet mixnet on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain

I installed lokinet on my ubuntu, but how do I find my lokinet address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed Lokinet by following [this guide](https://docs.loki.network/Lokinet/Guides/lokinet-linux-guide/), then you are "only" securing the network by running a daemon which is verifying the blockchain. At this point, you don't have any address yet. To get one, you will have to use a separate program which is in blockchain world usually called "wallet". I believe Loki has a nice guide which can help you to choose which wallet to use and how to use it, read it [here](https://docs.loki.network/Wallets/WalletsOverview/).

Be careful to use wallets (for any other coin around) from **trusted and verified sources only** since there was/is a lot of scammers around!